# Highlight parents in xml string

Tags: xml, algorithm, text

Say I have:

```
<ul>
    <li id="x">
        <a href="x">x</a>
    </li>

    <li id="y">
        <a href="y">y</a>

        <ul>
            <li id="z">
                <a href="z">z</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to add a class value to all the list items that are the parents of z. So, I want to modify y but not x.

Obviously, I can parse this into some kind of associative array and then recurse backwards. Any ideas how I can do it with just text processing (string replacing, regular expression, etc)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would use XSLT. You can specify to search for nodes that are ancestors of z .

Answer (score 2):

xpath has an ancestor-axis which includes all ancestors of the current context node.

//*[@id="z"]/ancestor::li

***** any element
**[@id="z"]** that has an attribute *id* with the value *z* (since the attribute is id there can(/should be) only be one such element)
**/ancestor::li** all *li* elements that are ancestors of that

see also: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp

Answer (score 1):

Example of the whole XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:variable name="ancestors" select="descendant::li[@id = 'z']/ancestor::li"/>

  <xsl:template match="li">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- test if current li is in the $ancestors node-list -->
      <xsl:if test="count($ancestors | .) = count($ancestors)">
        <xsl:attribute name="class">ancestor</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you parse it into a DOM and recurse backwards like you were thinking. Regular expressions don't work very well for nested structures with arbitrary nesting levels.

Answer (score 0):

Will add the attribute only to elements with a descendent element of 'z'.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input. I figured it was impossible without parsing (or using xsl, etc)... Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good fit for jQuery if that's available to you.

```
$("#z").parent().parent().addClass("foo");
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to John Sheehan's anwser:
With JQuery I'd rather use

`$('#z').parents('li').addClass('myClass');`
than relying on the actual structure.